# sql query with 2 table using joins

Tags: sql

Sorry for such a basic question but my SQL is weak.  I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

```
| CONTAINERIMAGEID |
|------------------|
|             1000 |
|             2000 |
|             3000 |
```

Table 2:

```
| FLAGGEDCONTAINERID | CONTAINERIMAGEID | REASONCODE |
|--------------------|------------------|------------|
|                  1 |             1000 |          5 |
|                  2 |             1000 |          8 |
|                  3 |             1000 |          4 |
|                  4 |             2000 |          4 |
|                  5 |             2000 |          5 |
```

I want to select all containerImageId's from CONTAINER_IMAGE and reason codes from FLAGGED_CONTAINER so that the results look likes this

```
| CONTAINERIMAGEID | CODES |
|------------------|-------|
|             1000 | 5 8 4 |
|             2000 |   4 5 |
```

but I do not know how to do the joins.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you don't need the first table, as all the information is from the second one (you can get `containerImageId` from `FLAGGED_CONTAINERS`)

Comment: actually I do need the first table because there are other items I need to select from it, however I left them out to make my example more simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you didnt specify what RDBMS you're using.

If it's **MySQL** you can do

```
SELECT c.*, q.codes
  FROM
(
  SELECT containerImageId, GROUP_CONCAT(reasonCode SEPARATOR ' ') codes
    FROM flagged_containers f
   GROUP BY containerImageId
) q JOIN container_image c 
    ON q.containerImageId = c.containerImageId
```

Output:

```
| CONTAINERIMAGEID | CODES |
|------------------|-------|
|             1000 | 5 8 4 |
|             2000 |   4 5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7620d4/2)** demo

---

If it's **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT c.*, q.codes
  FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT containerImageId, STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, reasonCode)
    FROM flagged_containers
    WHERE containerImageId = f.containerImageId
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ), 1, 1, '') codes
    FROM flagged_containers f
) q JOIN container_image c 
    ON q.containerImageId = c.containerImageId
```

Output:

```
| CONTAINERIMAGEID | CODES |
|------------------|-------|
|             1000 | 5 8 4 |
|             2000 |   4 5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79d4b/4)** demo

Comment: thank you peterm, I followed your example in sqlfiddle.  I should have mentioned that I am doing this in MS Sql Server.  forgive the omission, I'm not used to using this forum to ask for help

Comment: However I need to add that I follow the gist of what you are doing and think I can adapt this to my issue

Comment: I've just posted an update for SQL Server. SQL Server unfortunately still doesn't have a built in function for string aggregation. But it can be emulated in several ways (one of which is by using STUFF, FOR XML and a correlated subquery).